# how to implement a SetOnItemClickListener FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

how to implement a SetOnItemClickListener event in a Firebase RecyclerView Adapter?
I use the example of documentation, chat app:

```
 private FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_recycler);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatMessageViewHolder>(ChatMessage.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ChatMessageViewHolder.class, mRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageViewHolder chatMessageViewHolder, ChatMessage chatMessage) {
            chatMessageViewHolder.nameText.setText(chatMessage.getName());
            chatMessageViewHolder.messageText.setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
        }
    };
    recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, but this is the one I just quickly tried.

The `ChatMessageViewHolder` class has a member field where it keeps the root view for each chat message:

```
public static class ChatHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public ChatHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
```

We can use that `mView` member to get access to the clickable view. You *should* add a getter for `mView`, but I'm trying to minimize the changes here.

So then in `populateView` we can use the overload that has an additional `position` parameter and wire things up with an `OnClickListener` like this:

```
    mRecycleViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(Chat.class, R.layout.message, ChatHolder.class, mChatRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatView, Chat chat, final int position) {
            chatView.setName(chat.getName());
            chatView.setText(chat.getText());

            if (mAuthData != null && chat.getUid().equals(mAuthData.getUid())) {
                chatView.setIsSender(true);
            } else {
                chatView.setIsSender(false);
            }

            chatView.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "You clicked on "+position);
                    mRecycleViewAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();                        
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

The answers to this question offer tons of inspiration: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick). As long as you can determine the position that the user clicked on, you can use the `mRecycleViewAdapter.getRef(position)` snippet to get the database reference of the item that was clicked.

### Update

On second thought I might like this answer better https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/209103:

```
    mMessages.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.w(TAG, "You clicked on "+position);
            mRecycleViewAdapter.getRef(position).removeValue();
        }
    }));
```

It uses the `RecyclerItemClickListener` helper class from the answer I linked. And as already said: as long as you have a click/touch listener that tells you the position of the item that was selected, the rest FirebaseUI aspect of it will be the same: call `adapter.getRef(position)` to get a database reference for the selected item.

Comment: Frank, Very good! Thank you!
Their two options works perfectly, but in my opinion the first is better, though a little more extensive. For in it the "animation effect" when you click a Recycler view the item works perfectly in the second not.

I put the "View mView" in ChatHolder class and added the "chatView.mView.setOnClickListener". To get the position I unlike you, I got this: "recyclerView.getChildPosition (view)" in the "onClick (View view)".

Thanks again, and sorry for the delay to validate your answer.

Comment: Adding the "Firebase RecyclerView Adapter" class has the method "get Item (position)" that returns the related object. In the example above put in onClick: String myString = getItem (itemPosition);

Comment: As usual, you're as useful as hell. You won't believe how much I love your answers.

Comment: int position should not be final. it shows me warning

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Solution. This worked for me

**ViewHolder Class**

```
public class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView textViewName;
public TextView textViewRoll;
public TextView textViewAge;


public MyViewHolderClickListener mListener;

private String TAG= getClass().getSimpleName();

public static interface MyViewHolderClickListener{

    public void onTextViewNameClick(View view, int position);
    public void onTextViewRollClick(View view, int position);
}

public StudentViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewRoll = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRoll);
    textViewAge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAge);

    textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewRoll.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void bindToStudent(Student student){
    if (student == null) {
        return;
    }

    textViewName.setText("Name: " +  student.getName());
    textViewRoll.setText( "Roll: " + student.getRoll());
    textViewAge.setText( "Age: " +  student.getAge());
}

public void setCustomOnClickListener(MyViewHolderClickListener listener  ){
    this.mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick at " + getAdapterPosition());
    Log.d(TAG, "id: " + view.getId());

    if( mListener!= null ){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.textViewName:
                mListener.onTextViewNameClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.textViewRoll:
                mListener.onTextViewRollClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

 }



}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class StudentListAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Student, StudentViewHolder> {

Activity parentActivity;
StudentViewHolder.MyViewHolderClickListener myViewHolderClickListener;

private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

public StudentListAdapter(Activity mActivity, Class<Student> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<StudentViewHolder> viewHolderClass, Query ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    parentActivity = mActivity;
}


@Override
public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    StudentViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    // adding my MyViewHolderClickListener here
    viewHolder.setCustomOnClickListener(myViewHolderClickListener);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(StudentViewHolder viewHolder, final Student model, final int position) {

    Log.d(TAG, model.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, getRef(position).getKey());

    // bind view
    viewHolder.bindToStudent(model);
}


public void setMyViewHolderClickListener(StudentViewHolder.MyViewHolderClickListener listener){
    this.myViewHolderClickListener = listener;
}


}
```

**In Activity Class**

```
        mAdapter = new StudentListAdapter(this, Student.class, R.layout.list_item, StudentViewHolder.class, studentQuery);
    mAdapter.setMyViewHolderClickListener(new StudentViewHolder.MyViewHolderClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTextViewNameClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Name Click at " +position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextViewRollClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Roll Click at " +position);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```