# Filter in FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

On that question ( [how to implement a SetOnItemClickListener FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110497/how-to-implement-a-setonitemclicklistener-firebaserecyclerviewadapter)
)  I learned how to use the FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter to get the click of recycler view, perfect.

Now I need to filter RecyclerView items made with the FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter. In my business rule listo of the items and the user can filter them.

If it was manual, a list adding the adapter I know, but as the FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter is responsible to prepare / update the list, someone has a suggestion how to put a filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client-side filtering is not supported in the current version of FirebaseUI. It's on the roadmap, but not planned yet: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15.

In the meantime, you can either use [Firebase's built-in Query capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries) to limit the data. This has the advantage that only data matching the conditions will be downloaded from the server.

A great example of how advanced you can make this, is the "friend search" feature in the ShoppingList++ app of the Udacity course [Firebase Essentials for Android](https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009). You can find the crucial class [here](https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/udacity/firebase/shoppinglistplusplus/ui/sharing/AddFriendActivity.java) in Github, but I highly recommend taking the entire course to see how this works.

Comment: Hi @Frank, Im using this example from ShoppingList++ to filter in a SearchView inside a toolbar on my current app. But I have a question: is not so expensive make multipla calls to the client-side in this kind of short time? Is there any way to make it less expensive? using keepSync(true) or any other cache Firebase feature?

Thanks for your time!