# Filter the results received from firebase before supplying it to the Firebase List adapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-adapter, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and android.
I am populating a listview with data from firebase using firebase List adapter.
I understand that we can not chain filters in firebase.

Below is the code snippet from the activity. I created a firebase reference. Then I applied the equalTo filter to get items with category=clothes.

```
Query orderedActiveUserListsRef;

Firebase activeListsRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USER_LISTS)
                    .child(mEncodedEmail);

orderedActiveUserListsRef = activeListsRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("clothes");
```

I would like to further filter out results from orderedActiveUserListsRef before supplying it to the adapter.

One approach I found is creating an array by iterating the orderedActiveUserListsRef using the below code:

```
orderedActiveUserListsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String category = (String) messageSnapshot.child("category").getValue();
            Log.d("CatList",category);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

Please advise the best possible approach.
PS: I have denormalised the data.

Comment: why you need to supply it to firebase list adapter.

Comment: The list adapter is populating the listview.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380887/filter-in-firebaserecyclerviewadapter

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the link. Is it possible that we build an array out of it locally, and then pass it on to an array list adapter to populate the listview? Will that be efficient?

Comment: It sure is possible, because that's essentially what the Firebase*Adapters do. Have a look at their code if you need inspiration.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thanks a ton. I guess I will have to edit Firebase Adapter and create my own.