# Firebase UI RecyclerView onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to populate a RecyclerView. I managed to get click events from components of my item view (the title), but not for anywhere in the item view, which is what I need. I followed google sample.

In my Activity:

```
private void setRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_gigs);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Gig, GigViewHolder>(Gig.class,
            R.layout.list_item_card,
            GigViewHolder.class,
            reference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final GigViewHolder viewGig, Gig model, final int position) {

            viewGig.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "onItemClickGeneral: position " + position);
                    // this doesn't work
                }
            });
            viewGig.bindToGig(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "onItemClickTitle: position " + position);
                    // this works
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

and my ViewHolderClass:

```
public class GigViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

ImageView ivIconArtist;
TextView tvArtist;
TextView tvVenue;
TextView tvDate;

public GigViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    ivIconArtist = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_item_icon_artist);
    tvArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item_artist);
    tvVenue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item_venue);
    tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item_date);
}

public void bindToGig(Gig gig, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    tvArtist.setText(gig.getArtist());
    tvVenue.setText(gig.getVenue());
    tvDate.setText(gig.getDate());

    tvArtist.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

}

I tried the custom onclicklistener + interface suggested in other answers, no luck either.

Comment: try setting your click listener in GigViewHolder constructor like view.setOnClickListener(clickListener); As you have set your listener for artist title only then I think you will get callback on that textview click only.

Comment: Tried that before, that makesGigViewHolder to implement View.OnClickListener,, adding an onClick method that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think no need to implement onClickListener on ViewHolderClass as in bindToGig you are setting class level clickListener right.? then set the same clickListener to view which is your constructor reference.

Answer (score 16):

**Implementing click and long click listener for entire row / items in FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.**

I did this in this way.

> > First, define an interface in your `ViewHolder` class to send callbacks.
> >     Inside its constructor, you can set click/long-click listener for entire row or a single componnent.
> >     Then override `onCreateViewHolder` of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` where you will implement this interface.

**IMPLEMENTATION**

My `FirebaseViewHolder` class.

```
public class FirebaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mPostTitle;
    public TextView mPostDesc;

    public FirebaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_recyclerview);
        mPostTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_recyclerview_item);
        mPostDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc_recyclerview_item);

        //listener set on ENTIRE ROW, you may set on individual components within a row.
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemLongClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    private FirebaseViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

    //Interface to send callbacks...
    public interface ClickListener{
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(FirebaseViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }
}
```

Creating the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, FirebaseViewHolder> adapter = new   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, FirebaseViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.recyclerview_list_item,
            FirebaseViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(model.image_url)
                    .into(viewHolder.mImageView);
            Log.v(TAG, model.image_url);
            //viewHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            viewHolder.mPostTitle.setText(model.title);
            viewHolder.mPostDesc.setText(model.desc);
        }

        @Override
        public FirebaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            FirebaseViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new FirebaseViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item long clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };
```

Comment: mostly works, however I was having trouble calling `FirebaseViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);` on the second part. Managed to get it working with this instead:
                `View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                FirebaseViewHolder vh = new FirebaseViewHolder (v);
                vh.setOnClickListener(new SpellCardViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    ...
                    }
                });
                return vh;
            }
        };`

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers to this question. One that worked for me was the answer provided by `Frank van Puffelen` [how-to-implement-a-setonitemclicklistener-firebaserecyclerviewadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110497/how-to-implement-a-setonitemclicklistener-firebaserecyclerviewadapter)

**You need to change few things.**

Before `GigViewHolder` constructor inside your `public class GigViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder` define a global variable like this **`View itemView;`**

Inside `GigViewHolder` constructor, assign this variable the view passed as a parameter on your constructor like this **`this.itemView= view;`**

Then use this `itemView` in your `populateViewHolder` method as you had done as also shown

```
viewGig.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(Utils.TAG, "onItemClickGeneral: position " + position);
                // This WORKS, write your TODO here
            }
        });
```

You can also explore other options on the following links:
[RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick?page=2&tab=active#tab-top)