# Firebase Storage - Prevent Overwriting of Files

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-camera, firebase-storage

I am allowing users to take pictures and store them to Firebase. Below is my code that contains the intent to load the camera application, save the image, and then upload to the Firebase storage. The problem I am having is each subsequent upload to the Firebase Storage is overriding the previous upload, meaning I have 1 file in storage that keeps being overridden. I want to keep adding multiple files:

```
private void createAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_image_dialog_title);
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                    {getResources().getString(R.string.add_image_web), getResources().getString(R.string.add_image_camera), getResources().getString(R.string.add_image_gallery)},
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                    // of the selected item
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent toImageSearch = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, NewImageActivity.class);
                            startActivityForResult(toImageSearch, USE_WEB);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getApplication().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.camera_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

    );
    builder.create().

            show();
}
```

OnActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case USE_WEB:
            if (resultCode == CreateActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                resultImageURL = data.getStringExtra("result");
                mAddImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(resultImageURL)
                        .into(mImagePreview);
            }
            if (resultCode == CreateActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }

        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == CreateActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(imageBitmap);
            }
    }
}
```

Save to Firebase:

```
 private void encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    UploadTask uploadTask = mPollImageStorage.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Loading Photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            mAddImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            resultImageURL = downloadUrl.toString();
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(resultImageURL)
                    .into(mImagePreview);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a separate location or separate file name for each upload.

You can create a custom location like this:

```
 FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://myfirebaseproject.appspot.com");
            StorageReference fileRef =
                    storageRef.child(channelId)
                    .child(String.valueOf(message.getSender()))
                    .child(String.valueOf(message.getTimestamp()));

            UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(message.getAttachmentUri());
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    sendMessage(channelId, message.getMessageText(), taskSnapshot.getStorage().toString(), message.getAttachmentType(), callback);
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    callback.onError(e.toString());
                }
            });
```

You can see we are adding custom locations to our base storage reference so that we don't overwrite existing items.

Comment: How would I change the file name that is generated by the camera intent?

Comment: Where do you get the channelId and message instances?

Comment: Much appreciated, can you tell me why my clickListener isn't working as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275845/firebase-recyclerview-clicklistener-not-being-called-from-onstart/41276122?noredirect=1#comment69754365_41276122

Answer (score 1):

The location that you store your image is determined by what `mPollImageStorage` is referencing. If `mPollingStorage` always references the same place, ie, in your `onCreate` you do something like:

`StorageReference mPollingStorage = storageRef.child("polling.jpg");`

Then it will keep overriding `camerapic.jpg`. If you don't want to override it, you could set the image name to something like the time the image was taken or generate a UUID as per this stackoverflow post : [Store files with unique/random names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444685/store-files-with-unique-random-names)

Comment: I know in the real-time database there is a .push() method to generate a unique key, is there an equivalent for the storage?

Comment: I was just looking for something like that -- this post says to use a uuid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444685/store-files-with-unique-random-names

Comment: You can create a custom location like this:             FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://myfirebaseproject.appspot.com");
            StorageReference fileRef =
                    storageRef.child(channelId)
                    .child(String.valueOf(message.getSender()))
                    .child(String.valueOf(message.getTimestamp())); You can see we are adding custom locations to our base storage reference so that we don't overwrite existing items.