# FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter : Recyclerview ViewHolder setOnClickListener not working in Fragment:

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewholder

I tried many options and solutions but I am still not able to get on Click event on ViewHolder. i.e. `viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener` is not working in fragment. I have used same code in activity and its working perfectly but not in Fragment.

gradle dependecy:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0' <br>
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
```

Code:

```
public class OffersFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mMainView;


    private RecyclerView mBusinessOffersList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    public OffersFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);


        //------Recyclerview to show Business Gallery ------------//
        mBusinessOffersList = mMainView.findViewById(R.id.businessOffersList);
        mBusinessOffersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mBusinessOffersList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

      .
      .
      .
        if(currentUser!=null && mBusinessUserID != null){
        mdatabaseOffers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers")
                .child(BusinessCity).child(mBusinessUserID);
    }



        return mMainView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <EshopOffers, BusinessOffersViewHolder> mfirebaseRecycleAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EshopOffers, BusinessOffersViewHolder>
                ( EshopOffers.class,
                        R.layout.shop_offerslist_layout,
                        BusinessOffersViewHolder.class,
                        mdatabaseOffers) {


            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final BusinessOffersViewHolder viewHolder, EshopOffers model, int position) {


                //---tried--Method 1: Open new Activity on CLick----but no luck--------//

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        };mBusinessOffersList.setAdapter(mfirebaseRecycleAdapter);

    }




    public static class BusinessOffersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;
        public LinearLayout offerLayout;
        ImageView offerImage1;
        LinearLayout offerLayout2;
       // public RelativeLayout offerRLlayout;

        public BusinessOffersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

          //---tried--Method 2: Open new Activity on CLick----but no luck--------//

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("View Clicked", "View Clicked");
                }
            });

        }


    }
}
```

I have tried most of the solutions from: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and [how to implement a SetOnItemClickListener FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110497/how-to-implement-a-setonitemclicklistener-firebaserecyclerviewadapter?noredirect=1&lq=1) but no luck. :(

I have scratched my head for almost 2 days 3 nights but still going nowhere ...:( so now need your help..!

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo but I do not have any issue in fetching data using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.  my issue is, `viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener' is not working in fragment. Above code is perfectly working in Activity. there is something that viewHolder view is not accessible in fragment. Even there is no any error or warning when I use 'setOnClickListener' on this VH.