# getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() not changing database for recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have 2 buttons. On button click I decide which database to select for recyclerview. As for example on button B1's click, I set database DB1 for recyclerview. I am using firebaserecycleradapter.
The problem is, getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() for recyclerview doesn't seem to work from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter definiton but works from populateviewholder. But since I set query on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter definition, at the end the database to be selected doesn't change on button click.

Here's some code:

```
//global declaration
  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomeBlog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

//FirebaseRecyclerAdapter part:


             firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomeBlog, BlogViewHolder>(

                    HomeBlog.class,
                    R.layout.profile_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class,
                    query

//the query is the Firebase database that I want at a time.
//since getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() not reloading from here. query remains same.

            )
            {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, HomeBlog model, int position) {


                    final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                    final String postPosition = String.valueOf(position);

//getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() seems to load in populateviewholder though.
//this I checked using Toast.



                    viewHolder.setImage(post_key);

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            //other code


                        }
                    });

                }
            };

            mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);




//one button click example:
 grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //changing the query

                query = mDatabase.orderByChild("UserId").equalTo(userId);
                mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
                mBlogList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

I want to make sure the firebaserecycleradapter definition part also loads when I call getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(). Because it holds the query.
Is there some approach to do that? Or I am doing a completely wrong process?

Answer (score 0):

After you call `setAdapter()`, you can then use `notifyDataSetChanged()` on that adapter. Example:

```
mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then your data will be updated.

Comment: you want on button click for the adapter to update?

Comment: why dont you add the click listener in the holder class?

Comment: yes. What I want is on B1 click DB1 is selected for recyclerview and on B2 click DB2 is selected for recyclerview.

Comment: can you please elaborate your last comment?

Comment: this i mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110497/how-to-implement-a-setonitemclicklistener-firebaserecyclerviewadapter

Comment: Yes. This might work with a little modification in my code. Thank you.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct and upvote it so it can help other users also, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191475/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-zubayr).